# Looking for an Equivalent of GenerateTableFetch

Tags: apache-nifi

I use ExecuteSQLRecord to run a query and write to CSV format. The table has 10M rows. Although I can split the output into multiple flow files, the query is executed by only a single thread and is very slow.

Is there a way to partition the query into multiple queries so that the next processor can run multiple concurrent tasks, each one process one partition? It would be like:

GenerateTableFetch -> ExecuteSQLRecord (with concurrent tasks)

The problem is that GenerateTableFetch only accepts table name as input. It does not accept customized queries.

Please advise if you have solutions. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the concurrency on Nifi processors (by increase the number in Councurrent Task), you can also increase the throughput, some time it works :

[image: Nifi concurrency]

Also if you are working on the cluster, before the processor, you can apply load balancing on the queue, so it will distribute the workload among the nodes of your cluster (load balance strategy, put to round robin):

[image: load balancing nifi]

Check this, youtube channel, for Nifi antipatterns (there is a video on concurrency): [Nifi Notes](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcNsK56MZRXzPbRfe8sODWw)

Please clarify your question, if I didn't answer it.

Comment: Adding number of concurrent tasks only works if the incoming flow file contains multiple queries. I actually have concurrent setting, but it does not work. GenerateTableFetch can break one query into multiple queries, each of which looks like: SELECT * FROM T1 OFFSET x ROWS FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY. Then, the next processor can fire multiple tasks concurrently. However, GenerateTableFetch won't accept customized queries. This is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out an alternative way. I developed a Oracle PL/SQL function which takes table name as an argument, and produces a series of queries like "SELECT * FROM T1 OFFSET x ROWS FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY". The number of queries is based on the number of rows of the table, which is a statistics number in the catalog table. If the table has 1M rows, and I want to have 100k rows in each batch, it will produces 10 queries. I use ExecuteSQLRecord to call this function, which effectively does the job of NiFi processor GenerateTableFetch. My next processor (e.g. ExecuteSQLRecord again) can now have 10 concurrent tasks working in parallel.